# CliChing, an i-ching on command line in python

Tags: python, class

I've just developed my first python program!
In order to learn something more out of it I think the best idea and post it here. 
I'm just wondering if there is a better way to write this program.

It is a python program that brings "i-ching, the book of mutations" with the translation by 
Richard Wilhelm, on command line.

The complete project is on github:
https://github.com/roorco/CliChing/blob/master/cliching.py

Interesting to note: in order to recognize which hexagram the program extracts, it transforms the hexagram in a binary number. In coding this I suppose I understood how Leibniz discovered the binary number studying I-Ching.

Thanks to this exercise I understood better the classes in Python but still one thing is not clear for me:

if I wrote:

```
class Line(object):
    def intro():
        ...
```

and the end of the code I call:

```
Line().intro()
```

the result will be:

```
TypeError: intro() takes no arguments (1 given)
```

Why?
The only way I figure out is giving a 'x' argument to intro.
Other ways are possible?

If you like to, please leave me some feedback.

Comment: Methods need a `self` parameter.

Comment: Ah, of course! thank you, now it seems obvious but it was not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods that are defined within a class need to take self as a parameter. This is basically because they need to know which object the function is operating on. Take a look at these 2 links they do a pretty good job of explaining what `self` is and why we need to use it.

[What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

https://freepythontips.wordpress.com/2013/08/07/the-self-variable-in-python-explained/